# Обновление базы данных PHP

Tags: php, база-данных

Доброго времени суток, друзья. Столкнулся с весьма банальной проблемой обновления базы.

Есть код:
код PHP

```
mysql_query("UPDATE news SET marks=$marks WHERE post_id='$_GET[post_id]'");
```

Если написать аргумент, например `WHERE post_id='12'` , то обновлять будет, а если поставить переменную, как я показал в коде, то не обновляет, будто игнорирует переменную. В чём собственно проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE news SET marks=$marks WHERE post_id='{$_GET['post_id']}'");
// или
mysql_query("UPDATE news SET marks=$marks WHERE post_id='" . $_GET['post_id'] . "'");
```

Попробуйте вывести непосредственно сам запрос:

```
echo "UPDATE news SET marks=$marks WHERE post_id='{$_GET['post_id']}'";
и посмотрите что получится.
```

Не стоит использовать переменные из $_REQUEST в запросах к бд без предварительной обработки.

Comment: вот оно, вывел эхом сам запрос и там он не видет $_GET['post_id']

Comment: UPDATE news SET marks=2880 WHERE post_id=//ПУСТОТА//

Comment: хотя принтом вывожу $_GET[post_id] выводит нормально число, а в запросе игнорирует.

Comment: Проверьте на опечатки, и на возможное случайное присвоение.

Answer (score 0):

А переменная `$_GET[post_id]` приходит в сценарий?

Comment: да, вывожу её чуть выше условия.

Comment: Покажите кусок кода, начиная с того тестового вывода, и кончая запросом (если он не очень большой)

Answer (score 0):

В строках не может быть массивов. Нужно или экранировать `{$_GET[post_id]}`, или использовать конкатенацию `post_id='".$_GET[post_id]."'"`, ну или попробуйте присвоить значение другой переменной, а потом вставить ее в строку запроса.